# Recommended user video Like youtube

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a youtube like main page. With the code below I want to make videos that are recommended for my users.

The following code shows only a user's video.

```
<?php $query = "SELECT
                 user.uid,
                 user.user_name,
                 user.user_avatar,
                 user_posts.uid_dk,
                 user_posts.post_id,
                 user_posts.post_name,
                 user_posts.post_info,
                 user_posts.post_time,
                 user_posts.post_ext,
                 user_posts.post_num,
                 user_posts.post_views
                 FROM user 
                 JOIN user_posts 
                 ON user_posts.uid_dk = user.uid 
                 WHERE user_name='$user_name' LIMIT 5";
                 $run_query = mysql_query($query);
                 while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($run_query)){
                     $post_name=$data['post_name'];
                     $post_time = $data['post_time'];
                     $post_views = $data['post_views'];
                     $post_numid = $data['post_num'];
                     $post_id = $data['post_id'];
                     $user_name = $data['user_name'];
                     $user_avatar = $data['user_avatar'];
                 ?>

<div class="onerilent"><img src="<?php echo $user_avatar;?>"><?php echo $user_name ;?> Recommended for you</div>
<div class="onmnwrp">
   <div class="onmn">
     <div class="onmn_img"><img src="<?php echo $base_url.'user_uploads/'.$post_num;?>.png"></div>
     <div class="onmg_tit"><?php echo $post_name;?></div>
     <div class="onm_snm">gönderen: <?php echo $user_name;?></div>
     <div class="onm_tim"><?php echo $post_views;?> views</div>
   </div>
</div>
<?php  } ?>
```

I want to show this section only one time.

```
<div class="onerilent"><img src="<?php echo $user_avatar;?>"><?php echo $user_name ;?> Recommended for you</div>
```

Anyone can help me in this regard ?

Comment: Be careful with where `$user_name` is coming from here - that could be a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @halfer how can a fixed it ?

Comment: Have a look [at the top answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+sql+injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be with a counter, like this:

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT
        user.uid,
        user.user_name,
        user.user_avatar,
        user_posts.uid_dk,
        user_posts.post_id,
        user_posts.post_name,
        user_posts.post_info,
        user_posts.post_time,
        user_posts.post_ext,
        user_posts.post_num,
        user_posts.post_views
    FROM user 
    JOIN user_posts 
    ON user_posts.uid_dk = user.uid 
    WHERE user_name='$user_name' LIMIT 5";

    $run_query = mysql_query($query);

    $counter = 1;


    while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($run_query)){
        $post_name=$data['post_name'];
        $post_time = $data['post_time'];
        $post_views = $data['post_views'];
        $post_numid = $data['post_num'];
        $post_id = $data['post_id'];
        $user_name = $data['user_name'];
        $user_avatar = $data['user_avatar'];


        if($counter == 1){
            $counter++;
            echo '<div class="onerilent"><img src="'.$user_avatar.'">'.$user_name.' Recommended for you</div>';
        }
        ?>    

        <div class="onmnwrp">
            <div class="onmn">
                <div class="onmn_img"><img src="<?php echo $base_url.'user_uploads/'.$post_num;?>.png"></div>
                <div class="onmg_tit"><?php echo $post_name;?></div>
                <div class="onm_snm">gönderen: <?php echo $user_name;?></div>
                <div class="onm_tim"><?php echo $post_views;?> views</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
    }
    ?>
```

note the $counter variable is set to 1 before the loop, and inside the loop there is a condition to check if it is set to the value 1, and if it is, then it echo's your html and increments the $counter, so that it is no longer set to 1

Comment: It was very nice and explanatory answers. Thank you.